# How to show web content in android application without using webView

Tags: android, web-applications, android-library

i am still developing android static app in which all the content are static , all the content which is deign by me nothing is taken by website but now

#

i am starting to develop web app that is,  all content coming from website .
i searched lot of thing i got only "WebView" in which whole website will show in my WebView .
So there is a Problem, i want to get a specific content from any website like Event images from website and show in my Activity.
 Please help me to start web app development.

is there any api ??
Thanks in advance.

#

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my understanding, what you want to create is an Application that will show content from a website, but not using WebView.

For those webs that do not provide an API (your own website, for example), you may want to have a look at [JSOUP](http://jsoup.org) and give it a try.

For those webs that have API (for example: twitter), you should read its document and try some HTTP request.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to write APIs which'll allows you to make requests from your android code to the server code. Using these requests you'll be able to fetch data stored on a web server in a friendly format that can be used to display content on your android app.

Answer (score 0):

I see you have clear some concepts, like Web app, browser, events. But remember the Logic from webApp is with javascript, so the Webview download the HTML to the device and if you have activate javascript in the webview thats work fine, remember you have some restriction with the hardware and process with webapps.

But android developer has a [tutorial to create web apps.](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/index.html)

When you create a native app doesnt mean is static,  you can use Json, XML, Rest API, Web services, etc. to comunicate  with a web server.

I recommend see how connect android app with external resources and webserver, [here is an example.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html)